# sql pivot character variable

Tags: sql, pivot

in order to pivot table within sql, suppose the following Occupation table contain 3 feature i.e. ID, FirstName, and Occupation, as follow:

[image: Occupation Table]

then in order to return pivot base on its occupation i tried the following:

```
select actress,
       Dancer,
       Photographer,
       Salesman
       from Occupation o 
       pivot (max(o.FirstName) for o.Occupation in ([Actress], [Dancer], [Photographer], [Salesman])) as pivotable
```

[image: Pivot]

While the result return NULL. What suppose to achieve in here was the pivot only contain Name of Person base on their Occupation without return all Null, as following table

[image: Target Result]

Comment: instead of images please share table scripts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, in your data, there is no relationship between each person, so it can't be shown on the same row (what links Juli with Satria that you want to see them on the same row?).

If you can generate a row number by each job, you can mix them together by their cardinal position of each job.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Jobs') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Jobs

CREATE TABLE #Jobs (
    ID INT,
    Name VARCHAR(100),
    Job VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #Jobs (
    ID,
    Name,
    Job)
VALUES
    (1001, 'Satria', 'Dancer'),
    (1002, 'Juli', 'Actress'),
    (1003, 'Mario', 'Actress'),
    (1004, 'Memet', 'Salesman'),
    (1005, 'Alan', 'Photographer'),
    (1006, 'Kiky', 'Photographer'),
    (1007, 'Chacha', 'Photographer'),
    (1008, 'Joko', 'Actress'),
    (1009, 'Juni', 'Dancer'),
    (1010, 'Putra', 'Salesman')



;WITH JobNumbering AS
(
    SELECT
        J.Job,
        J.Name,
        Ranking = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY J.Job ORDER BY J.ID)
    FROM
        #Jobs AS J
)
SELECT
    P.Actress,
    P.Dancer,
    P.Photographer,
    P.Salesman
FROM
    JobNumbering AS J
    PIVOT (
        MAX(J.Name) FOR J.Job IN ([Actress], [Dancer], [Photographer], [Salesman])
    ) AS P
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to only select the required column from Occupation table. Use CTE or derived table to do that.

```
select actress,
       Dancer,
       Photographer,
       Salesman
from   (
              select FirstName, Occupation 
              from Occupation 
       ) o 
       pivot 
       (
              max(o.FirstName) 
              for o.Occupation in ([Actress], [Dancer], [Photographer], [Salesman])
       ) as pivotable
```

Answer (score 1):

You should first order them in the desired way in source table part of pivot using a row_number function

<kbd>**[See working demo](http://rextester.com/HGP60078)**</kbd>

```
select 
    actress,
    Dancer,
    Photographer,
    Salesman
from 
(
select 
   FirstName,
   Occupation,-- see no Id here in select list to explicitly avoid ordering by id
   rn= row_number() over (partition by Occupation order by id asc)
from 
Occupation 
)  o 
pivot 
(
    max(o.FirstName) 
    for o.Occupation in 
    (
        [Actress], [Dancer], [Photographer], [Salesman]
    )
) as pivotable
order by rn --explicitly added to get desired results
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
-- incase u dont want null to be populated as a value in the output
  isnull(dancer,' ') as dancer,
  isnull(actress,' ') as actress,
  isnull(salesman,' ') as salesman,
  isnull(photographer,' ') as photographer
from
(
 select firstname,
 occupation,
 row_number() over (partition by occupation order by occupation) as ranks
 from Occupation
) a
pivot
(
min(firstname)
for occupation in ([Dancer],[actress],[salesman], [photographer])
) as piv
order by ranks
```

Comment: work well close to what i want to achieve, but what i mean to return not all null as table desired result. Thanks anyway...